# When does Workbox's precaching go into effect?

Tags: javascript, workbox

I got a error; the worbox precaching my Static files，for example js or css；At this time I setted workbox.routing.registerRoute is don't work；

[image: Code]

[image: server-worker cache]

[image: After the refresh file is not from cache]

If I delete workbox precaching （must sure server worker cache file），After the refresh file is from cache；

[image: delete worbox precaching]

Comment: my env is localhost

Answer (score 1):

Responses won't come from the service worker until the registered service worker takes control of the current page. Depending on how you're testing things, that might not happen until you've closed all of your previously open tabs for your origin.

You can learn more at "[The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle)".

I'd recommend starting from scratch by using a Chrome Incognito window, going through the SW registration, and then reloading that Incognito tab. At that point, the newly registered SW should be in control of the page, and you should see your precached JavaScript being used to satisfy the subresource request.

In general, if you are using Workbox precache and runtime routing in the same service worker, and you list you call to precaching first (which is what you're doing), then precaching will take precedence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; This error is one of my problems. The error is caused by my failure to properly handle the HTML file routing to /, which caused the server worker to fail to successfully enter the activate life cycle. Sorry to trouble you;